# Sql for invoices with more than 50% paid

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm breaking my  head around this query for a while now so I thought I'd give it a shot here at SO.

I have the following tables:

```
quotes(id, quote_version_id, etc for brevity)
quote_versions(id, quote_id, etc)
v2_quote_payments(id, quote_id, amount, etc)
quote_product_items(quote_version_id, amount, discount, price, etc)
quote_freight_items(quote_version_id, amount, price, etc)
quote_service_items(quote_version_id, amount, price, etc)
```

A quote has many versions, however the quote_version_id indicates the `current_version`. I need to get the quotes that have more than 50% payments made (`sum(v2_quote_payments.amount > (total_freights + total_products + total_services)`

So far I have this, but the sums are not consistent (total_freights, etc), for some reason I have diplicates in the sum, maybe due to the different `quote_versions`?

```
    SELECT 
        quotes.id as quote_id, 
        quote_versions.id as quote_version,
        sum(v2_op_payments.amount) as total_paid, 
        coalesce(sum(quote_product_items.amount * quote_product_items.price * (1 + (quote_product_items.discount/100))), 0) + 
        coalesce(sum(quote_service_items.amount * quote_service_items.price), 0) +
        coalesce(sum(quote_freight_items.amount * quote_freight_items.price * (1 + (quote_freight_items.discount/100))), 0),
        sum(quote_product_items.amount * quote_product_items.price * (1 + (quote_product_items.discount/100))) as total_prod,
        sum(quote_service_items.amount * quote_service_items.price) as total_serv,
        sum(quote_freight_items.amount * quote_freight_items.price * (1 + (quote_freight_items.discount/100))) as total_freight
    FROM 
        `quotes` 
        INNER JOIN `v2_op_payments` ON `v2_op_payments`.`quote_id` = `quotes`.`id` 
        INNER JOIN `quote_versions` ON `quote_versions`.`quote_id` = `quotes`.`id` 
        INNER JOIN `v2_production_orders` ON `v2_production_orders`.`quote_id` = `quotes`.`id` 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `quote_product_items` ON `quote_product_items`.`quote_version_id` = `quote_versions`.`id` 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `quote_freight_items` ON `quote_freight_items`.`quote_version_id` = `quote_versions`.`id` 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN `quote_service_items` ON `quote_service_items`.`quote_version_id` = `quote_versions`.`id` 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN quote_cancellations ON quote_cancellations.quote_id = quotes.id 
    WHERE 
        `quote_cancellations`.`id` IS NULL 
        AND `quote_versions`.`approved` = 1 
        AND (quote_versions.id = quotes.quote_version_id) 
    GROUP BY
        quotes.id
```

I do these sums in order to check if the total of each quote is being calculated correctly before proceeding.

The other conditions only check that the quote is approved, and that there's no cancellation item for the quote.

What am I missing here?

Thanks,

**EDIT**

Here's the sqlfiddle for the schema and the query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23ff06/1

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: It looks like you are joining all versions of the quote and grouping them together. Wouldn't it be more accurate to join based on the current quote version instead?

Comment: @DanneManne its true, I've tried modifying it but have the same result, since in the original question the sql statement has the condition `AND (quote_versions.id = quotes.quote_version_id) `. 

@Strawberry, I'm doing that, I'll post it when I have it ready.

Comment: @Strawberry I can't seem to build a schema from my exported db data, it's too large, should I link to a file with the exported data?

Comment: @Strawberry here's a link to the file. It will create the tables required and also populate it with the same data I'm using to test. https://www.dropbox.com/s/shot73wqnv9qble/velosa_dev.sql?dl=0

Comment: I don't think we need to see the whole thing - just enough to be properly representative of the problem. Surely you can squeeze it down to 8000 characters - so everyone has a chance to play along!

Comment: @Strawberry the data is not very much. Even just creating the db fills out the 8k chat limit.

Comment: There are approximately 15 - 20 columns in this problem. There's no way a schema comprising 8 tables and a total of 20 columns is going to add up to 8k characters! You don't have to provide a fiddle, but no one wants to be faffing about with mysterious zip files.

Comment: @Strawberry I understand. There are way more columns in all the tables, and the total amount is 20k, I've removed some items and still it's 15k. The file I uploaded in the dropbox link is just text with .sql extension. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Strawberry so after removing some columns from the db to save chars, I was able to create it in sqlfiddle, here it is: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/23ff06/1. I hope you can help me out.

Comment: I know it's tremendously popular but, personally, I find a naming policy that leads to statements like this absolutely infuriating... `quote_versions.id = quotes.quote_version_id`. Further, your schema presently includes some 60 columns, whereas only approximately 20 of them seem relevant to this problem (admittedly still quite a large number). Can you not simply reduce the problem to the relevant columns. Then I feel like we would have a chance of helping.

Comment: @Strawberry ok I'll remove some other columns so the schema is clearer, thanks!